# An upper bound on the sum of the lengths of chords

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-geometry

**Problem:** Several chords are drawn in a circle of radius $1$, and each diameter of the circle intersects no more than four of them. Prove that the sum of their lengths does not exceed  13.

I couldn't make any progress. I just tried putting an upper bound on the number of diagonals (possibly 6?). This is supposed to be a pigeonhole principle problem but I have no clue where and how  to use the principle in this problem 
Someone please help me. Hints would also be great.

Comment: $4\pi < 13$. My guess is you can show that the sum of their lengths does not exceed $4\pi$. $\qquad$

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Comment: Never mind, it's on page 189 of Genkin and Fomin, Mathematical Circles. Maybe check to see whether there are solutions in the book?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, solutions are not given for the  chapter the problem is from.

Comment: @aventurin, i think you are right, since otherwise the problem is trivialised.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thanks for the hint. But I am unable to prove that. I approached with the arc-chord inequality, trying to show that sum of the lengths of the chords is less than two times the circumference. Can you prove or give another hint?

Comment: **each diameter of the circle intersects no more than four of them** - This statement is key.

Comment: Yes, now i am able to prove it. Thanks

Comment: Good, Amy. Let me encourage you to write up and post a solution as an answer.

Comment: Suppose instead of chords they are arcs.  Can one prove the same thing?  If so, then it's also true of chords because the chord is shorter than the corresponding arc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I did it.

Answer (score 2):

For a chord of length $l$, one gets two arcs each  of length greater than $l$. The other arc is the one diametrically opposite to the given arc.

Now if the sum of the lengths of the chords $> 13$ then the sum of the lengths of the arcs "covered" $> 26$ > four times the circumference.

So,  at least one point must belong to the arcs or diametrically opposite arcs of at least five chords. But this is a contradiction as the diameter formed by this point and center will pass through at least five chords.

So, the sum of the lengths of the chords cannot exceed 13.